# Group_by mulitple variables but keep all in original dataframe

Tags: r

I got a dataframe that looks like this:

`ID1 STID MUNID YEAR SEX AGE POP`

I am using the `group_by` function to group STID, MUNID, YEAR, SEX and AGE to get the sum of the population with `summarise(pop=sum(pop))`. I cannot use the ID1 in the group_by since it will mess with the results but I want to keep it in the final dataframe. What are my alternatives or option to use so I can keep the ID1 in the end?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `paste` the values of 'ID1' or create a `list` column in `summarise` and then either `split` or `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(STID, MUNID, YEAR, SEX, AGE) %>%
   summarise(pop = sum(pop), ID1 = list(ID1), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   unnest(ID1)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful but unfortunately the number of observations goes up by a lot. I think it may be due to how the data is. Is there another option to do this?

Comment: @BoniPhila you can keep the ID1 as list column and skip the `unnest`.  or use `toString(ID1)` to paste

Comment: @BoniPhila Do you only want a subset of ID1?  I didn't correctly understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry I’m not good with the terms. I basically want to just have the ID1 next to the results of the population sum from grouping STID, MUNID, YEAR, SEX, AGE.

Comment: @BoniPhila yes, that i understand.  But suppose your ID1 have values 1 to 10, for  the first group (that includes the STID = 1, MUNID= 1, year = 1989, SEX = 'm', AGE =25), it implies there are 10 elements of ID1 needs to be crammed into a single row and that can be possible with a list column or you paste them 1,2,3,...10 in a single row

Comment: @BoniPhila may be you have something different in your mind.  Without a reproducible example and expected output it is not clear.  Sorry

Comment: Thank you @akrun. If it helps, the ID1 will be repeated for multiple instances of STID and MUNID. I may create an alternative id with pasting  MUNID, YEAR, SEX, AGE (while keeping ID1) and just joining to the resulting dataframe from the ``summarise(pop=sum(pop))``